# How do you change an instance variables property from a different class

Tags: objective-c, properties, instance-variables

If I had a label in one class and wanted to change what text it displayed, how could I this from a different class?

Comment: Show your code and give some more context then I am sure you will get the one or other response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In objective-c you have `properties` for effectively automating the creation of getters and setters for accessing instance variables.

```
@interface MyClass
{
    UILabel *instanceLabel; //Not required, but I find it can make it clearer
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *instanceLabel;

@end



@implementation MyClass

@synthesize instanceLabel; //Not required as of XCode 4.4
@end
```

Then from your other class its a simple case of using the dot operator to access those properties.

```
myClassInstance.instanceLabel.text = @"newText";
```

You don't have to use the dot operator:

```
[myClassInstance instanceVariable].text = @"newText";
```

Comment: would i need to import a header into the myClassInstance class?

Comment: Yes. You will also need to create an instance of MyClass to use.

Answer (score -1):

Usually one's using set-functions for this.

ie. pseudocode:

```
class YourClass 
{
    private var str;

    public YourClass(var str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public setString(var str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }

}




class SecondClass 
{
    private final YourClass myInstance;

    public SecondClass(final YourClass myInstance)
    {
        this.myInstance = myInstance;
    }

    public performChange()
    {
        myInstance.setString("hello");
    }
}
```

Calling SecondClass::performChange() would then change "YourClass myInstance's" instance variable to "hello".